# WMB - Is it possible to inject esql commands?

Tags: sql-injection, messagebroker

Well, the title is quite self - explanatory.
Is it possible somehow to inject commands into IBM WMB, or is it injection- safe system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only possible if you have written some really insecure ESQL in the first place.

If you have a compute node which uses the EVAL function then ESQL may be injected however the source of injection is still under control of the ESQL author.

Best practice advice is to avoid the use of this operator altogether.

The other thing that is possible that is not directly ESQL related is the use of the PASSTHRU statement to pass SQL directly to a database. The resulting SQL does not use parameter markers etc so failure to validate the input to the PASSTHRU function could also allow injection on the db.

Best practice is to avoid the use of both the EVAL and PASSTHRU statements altogether.

Comment: Are there any built-in functions you'd recommend to sanitize user input for use in ESQL?